# Docusign Signing Groups

Tags: docusignapi

I created an account in the Docusign Sandbox to evaluate the product. My main goal is to create a signing group but before that I would like to get the list of signing groups with RestSharp.

**[EDIT]**

```
docusign.configureApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi");
var login = docusign.LoginDocusign(USERNAME, PASSWORD);    

var client = new RestClient(login.BaseUrl);
var request = new RestRequest("signing_groups", Method.GET);
string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + USERNAME + "\", \"Password\":\"" + PASSWORD + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + INTEGRATOR_KEY + "\"}";
request.AddHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
Debug.WriteLine(content);
```

However the content returns

error code : "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PERMISSIONS"
message: "This Account lacks sufficient permissions."

I thought demo accounts have almost the same permissions as a premium account. Is there a setting somewhere to enable this?

I am certain that the authentication is correct when I request for list of groups, the content returns all of my groups.

```
var request = new RestRequest("groups", Method.GET);
```

Comment: Please provide the trace (what was sent/received) from the DocuSign platform. Or, at a minimum, show what was sent. Use requestb.in or alternative.

Comment: Apparently the feature was disabled in my account. I could not event create signing groups using the Docusign interface. I had to call customer support, it took a while for them to get at it but they finally enabled it. There was nothing wrong with the code in the first place!

Comment: Thank you for the update! Glad that it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with RestSharp, but my suspicion is that there's a problem with the request.

To diagnose: first start with making a call to DocuSign and use the [Request Log facility](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to see what is being sent.

If the incoming request can't be matched to your account, or fails some initial filters, then the request will not reach your account. In that case, use [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/) (free) to see what you're sending.

**Also,** I don't see where you are requesting the accountId and base URL from DocuSign. (Using https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information)

That's the first step for an API integration since you can't predict which platform the user's account is running on.

Comment: I updated the question and included login to docusign. login.BaseUrl inlcudes base Url and accountid. I also enabled Request log